# Missing valve part from Marzocchi MX Pro 2003- how does it work?

Tags: fork

I'm trying to figure out if I can make a replacement part for an old pair of Marzocchi MX Pro 2003 forks. Its part of the rebound damping rod and is the metal bit in this photo on the top where the hex rod is sticking out. Does anyone have more info about this piece?[image]

Comment: I recommend you try to buy just that part from your MZ dealer, as these pieces are really small and with small tolerances. Maybe this can help you: http://my-sport.spb.ru/manual_1/2005-mx-pro-eta.pdf MZ provides an awful customer support (or at least it used to until a few years ago), so if you're unlucky, try here: http://marzocchiworkshop.blogspot.com Hope one of these links helps you. Good luck.